# page curl animation between intent in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

I am working on animation and now I have to implement page curl animation between intents(views or layout) but I found out that there is no native api or library that can be used to implement this in Android. if anybody could suggest anything, would be very great or provide me some direction to implement this in android such as by using open GL. Thanks

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/PageCurl

Answer (score 0):

there are few projects available on github:

- [MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl)
- [harism/android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

By using it ,you can easily integrate page curl in your project.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thanks for links, I already tried these links but these project are only for pages not for view or intent. These projects can be used by converting layout into bitmap but which is not good solution and it will be kind of static things.

Answer (score 0):

What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
1. Downloaded pagecurl project
2. Imported to Eclipse ->API level 16
3. Created AVD with option GPU on
4. Run the application
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

```
Expected
Should show the Pagecurl but 
Actual
No rendering,Black screen
What version of the product are you using? 
On what operating system?
```

Windows 7 32bit,Android Emulator

Please provide any additional information below.